# Augmented Reality, not disappear the object on screen when camera out the image

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I use `Vuforia` and `Unity` to build an android AR app. I follow guide on youtube. And when phone's camera scan the image target, the house object appear on the image target. But when I get the image target out phone's camera, the house object isn't removed and it still appear on screen.

Comment: Check out the Books sample app to see example of moving augmentation from target to screen space.

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade: Could you share me link that example? Thanks!

Comment: I get this detail from the below link https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/moving-object-tilting-image-target

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Extended Tracking? Check the option in the inspector of your image target if the extended tracking is on.

For more information about extended tracking please refer to this [Vuforia Guide](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the house to disappear when tracking is lost, try attaching DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs from under Vuforia/Scripts to your game object.

Specifically look at OnTrackingLost - it disables rendering and collision.

Good luck!